# Django DRF elastic search dsl, Apply functional boosting based on another field numerical value

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am trying to tune the relevance of my field search result based on another field numerical value (the field is in another model). Looking at the [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/boosts.html#boosts-functional-boosts) it seems that *functional boosts* is what I need for my usecase.

Note that I am using the [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf); package.

My use case:

1. I have a search field where users can search for companies based on the company name.
2. I want to return the company names that match the query where sorting (relevance) depends on the company's net asset, where the higher the number, the more relevant (field in another model)

Model definition:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CompanyNetAsset(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    assets = models.IntegerField
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my es document:

```
...
custom_stop_words = token_filter(
    'custom_stopwords',
    type='stop',
    ignore_case=True,
    stopwords=['the', 'and']

)


html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=["lowercase", "asciifolding", custom_stop_words],
    char_filter=["html_strip"],
)


@INDEX.doc_type
class CompanyDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')

    name = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
        }
    )

    class Django:
        model = Company
```

and here is the DocumentViewSet:

```
class CompanyDocumentViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    """The Company Document view."""
    serializer_class = CompanyDocumentSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    document = CompanyDocument
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        SearchFilterBackend,
    ]
    search_fields = (
        'name'
    )

    filter_fields = {
        'id': None,
        'name': 'name.raw',

    }
```

Any idea how I can achieve this using the drf ES package?

**UPDATE**

here's an example query:

```
 /api/v1/employers/companies/?search=name:foundation%20center

 "results": [
        {
            "id": 469329,
            "name": "THE FOUNDATION CENTER",
            "city": "NEW YORK",
            "state": "NY"
        },
        {
            "id": 323012,
            "name": "OVERTURE CENTER FOUNDATION",
            "city": "MADISON",
            "state": "WI"
        },
        {
            "id": 367286,
            "name": "PEACE CENTER FOUNDATION",
            "city": "GREENVILLE",
            "state": "SC"
        },
       ...
```

And here is a son output of the document:

```
{'settings': {'number_of_shards': 1,
  'number_of_replicas': 1,
  'analysis': {'analyzer': {'html_strip': {'tokenizer': 'standard',
     'filter': ['lowercase', 'asciifolding', 'custom_stopwords'],
     'char_filter': ['html_strip'],
     'type': 'custom'}},
   'filter': {'custom_stopwords': {'ignore_case': True,
     'stopwords': ['the', 'and'],
     'type': 'stop'}}}},
 'mappings': {'properties': {'id': {'type': 'integer'},
   'city': {'type': 'text'},
   'state': {'type': 'text'},
   'name': {'analyzer': 'html_strip',
    'fields': {'raw': {'analyzer': 'keyword', 'type': 'text'}},
    'type': 'text'}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

ES doesn't support query-time joins so you'll need to replicate the `CompanyNetAsset` attributes in the `Company` model to be able to let the `assets` influence your sorting.

In practical terms, adjust the `Company` model like so:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    assets = models.IntegerField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then adjust the `Document`:

```py
@INDEX.doc_type
class CompanyDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')

    name = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
        }
    )

    assets = fields.IntegerField(attr='assets')

    class Django:
        model = Company
```

Finally, reindex your docs and define the sort:

```py
class CompanyDocumentViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    """The Company Document view."""
    serializer_class = CompanyDocumentSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    document = CompanyDocument
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        SearchFilterBackend,
    ]
    search_fields = (
        'name'
    )

    filter_fields = {
        'id': None,
        'name': 'name.raw',

    }
   
    # Define ordering fields        # <--
    ordering_fields = {
        'assets': None
    }

    # Specify default ordering      
    ordering = ('assets')
```

To enforce the [sort order via the URI](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage_examples.html#ordering), run:

```sh
GET /api/v1/employers/companies/?search=name:foundation%20center&ordering=-assets
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do at index time to apply some weighting whereby making the company_name more relevant given its asset?

Comment: Index-time boosting is discouraged because it's inflexible -- if you wanted to change your boosting logic, you'd have to reindex time and time again. On the other hand, query-time boosting with a value from one of the doc's fields can be easily achieved through [field value factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) function score queries. I'm sure there are pyDSL bindings for that!